# Where has Deke gone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

**Note**: this question has no spoilers but possible answers surely would have spoilers, so please mask the answers to prevent spoiling.

In Season 5 Episode 22 of Marvel's Agents of SHIELD, I understood everything about the episode, but I have one doubt: I see Deke in part of the episode, but at some point I don't see him anymore, and they don't talk about him anymore. Did I miss something? Why is he not appearing anymore, how is he and what is he doing? (If he is alive)

**EDIT:** I double checked after the suggestion by @Paulie_D and it seems he just decided to leave the group, but still since he comes from the future, and since other characters made the hypothesis that he may disappear, then is he supposed to disappear after all the events happened in the episode?

Comment: He left....he said he would during the episode....or did he? :)

Comment: I double checked and you are right, but still since he comes from the future, and since many people made the hypothesis that he may disappear, then is he supposed to disappear after all the events happened in the episode?

Comment: I [was wondering](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12479/358) if this could be answered now (at least the last question) given the logic of Endgame.

Comment: I'm doubtful if *Endgame* actually answers this question **specifically**

Comment: @paulie I think it's safe to say that he didn't disappear (like _bamf_ disappear), oh well maybe we'll find out tomorrow night 8, 7 central!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the producers took him away from the scene so they did not have to explain what happens to him with the time loop breaking. I have a theory, but it may contain spoilers:

> But I think Deke was primarily responsible for breaking the time loop. What if his return to the past was a random event (as it seemed) and happened only in that timeline, in which the time loop was broken? Deke made his contributions since his return to the past, but that events could somehow have occurred without him having gone back to the past in the previous timelines, there are several moments that he seems useless in the past. The ending would be very similar without him, Coulson did not take the serum also in the other timelines (he does not appear in the flashbacks of Episode 8), but with Deke's speech to Daisy about team unity, changed the way that she and everyone acted (with Mack as the new leader and Fitz and May set out to rescue Polly and Mack) and, perhaps, influenced her speech to the Talbot, which resulted in an event that she locates the serum left by Coulson in his glove, opening up an opportunity she might has not had in the other timelines. In the other timelines, Talbot absorbs Daisy and destroys Earth, the other team members blame her for it, because of his decisions, and the team struggles to work together, as shown in the flashbascks of episode 8.